# Trouble installing pandas package on Python via PiP

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip

I want to install the pandas package on my Python. I am using pip to do it so I executed

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

I get an error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions: 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.15.0rc1)No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3
```

I suspect it has something to do with my numpy version not being up to date, but I already attempted to be upgrade it and it was apparentlly up to date. I am using Windows 7 and Python 3.4.3.

Comment: This issue thread may help: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697

Comment: Do you really need python3.4? I guess, it is fixed and not an issue in python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling Numpy and installing it again?